# Generating 2nd Degree Polynomials Given 3-Tuples

Tags: perl

The purpose of this code is to define a sub apply_2nd_deg_polys that takes a list of anonymous 2nd degree
polynomials and a list of numbers and applies each polynomial to each number in the list. 
Any help is appreciated! (:

```
my @coeffs = ([1,2,3], [4,5,6]);
my @polys = gen_2nd_deg_polys(@coeffs);
my @numbers = (1..5);
my @poly_maps = apply_2nd_deg_polys2(\@polys, \@numbers);
```

The output should be:

```
[('1x^2 + 2x + 3 at x = 1 is ', 6), ('4x^2 + 5x + 6 at x = 1 is ', 15), ('1x^2 + 2x + 3 at x = 2 is ', 11), ('4x^2 + 5x + 6 at
x = 2 is ', 32), ('1x^2 + 2x + 3 at x = 3 is ', 18), ('4x^2 + 5x + 6 at x = 3 is ', 57), ('1x^2 + 2x + 3 at x = 4 is ', 27),
('4x^2 + 5x + 6 at x = 4 is ', 90), ('1x^2 + 2x + 3 at x = 5 is ', 38), ('4x^2 + 5x + 6 at x = 5 is ', 131)]
```

Here is the code I have so far...

```
sub apply_2nd_deg_polys{
    my @list = @_;
    my @polys = @{%_[0]}; my @numbers = @{@_[1]};
    push @list, $polys[0][i];
    push @list, $polys[i][0];
    return @list;

}
```

Here is my WORKING Python variation of it:

```
def apply_2nd_deg_polys(polys,numbers):
    newlist = []
    for number in numbers:
        newlist.append(polys[0](number))
        newlist.append(polys[1](number))
    return newlist
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignoring almost everything in your question, a (perhaps overly literal) translation of the Python code to Perl is:

```
sub apply_2nd_deg_polys {
    my ($polys, $numbers) = @_;
    my $newlist = [];
    for my $number (@$numbers) {
        push @$newlist, $polys->[0]->($number);
        push @$newlist, $polys->[1]->($number);
    }
    return $newlist;
}
```

Comment: I actually think that this works. I'm new to perl, though, so how do I print out poly_maps (or what was returned from this) onto the console? I tried print @poly_maps and I think it gave me a memory location.

Comment: @TerikBrunson That code returns a reference to an array. You can try `my $ref = apply_2nd_deg_polys(...); print "@$ref\n";` but if any of the elements are references, that won't be very helpful either. Try `use Data::Dumper; print Dumper($ref);` to see what's in it.

Comment: Yes, that worked. As a side note, do you know how I can write that same thing, but with each pushed element separated by a comma? thank you (:

Comment: @TerikBrunson I don't understand the question. Do you mean it should return a string (with commas in it)?

Comment: I think it's fine that it returned a reference to an array, because I can output it. But in the assignment, the output is supposed to be separated by commas, and surrounded by parenthesis. I easily remedied this in python, but I don't know the syntax to alter in in Perl. Does that make sense?

Comment: @TerikBrunson Do you mean like this? `print "(", join(", ", @$ref), ")\n";`